# mapping Unicode to emoji encoding table

Tags: android, json, unicode, emoji, spannable

I have response from server like this json

```
   "content": "\\u062a\\u0637\\u0628\\u064a\\u0642 \\u0645\\u0645\\u064a\\u0632     \\u0627\\u0644\\u0634\\u0643\\u0631 \\u0644\\u0645\\u0646 \\u0633\\u0627\\u0647\\u0645 \\u0641\\u064a\\u0647"
```

it represents emoj

I need to convert each emotion to the same code as in emoji code table
http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#emoji-modal

The problem is that i can't map encoding from response json to the encoding in the table

any help please ???

i will map each emoj to corresponding url in table emoj and display it in spannedImage

Comment: How is that response supposed to represent emoji? All of the codepoints in it are Arabic letters.

Comment: sorry , that content arabic yes but others contain emoji , so how can i convert that content to arabic as textView displays "\\u062a\\u0637\\u0628\\u064a\\u0642" not arabic letters

Comment: sounds like 'font-awesome' google it.. you can try the github project which has the glyph so it will provide you mapping, you can edit it using a freeware font editor..